# Knockout.js set class on filter collection if observable array matches its filter

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to get my head around some knockout.js prinicples and i have been playing around with some examples ive found in jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/188/

```
self.activeFilter = ko.observable(self.filters[0].filter);//set a default filter
```

Also this line above which sets the default filter..how can i modify this line to enable me to set this default filter to also have a class for "selected"

As you can see from above i have managed to get the a-z filter working but have two additional requirements.

1.) How can i apply a class to all letters that match the filter (so if there are surnames beginning with A then that needs to have a class added)

2.) What is the easiest way to limit each filter etc with paging?

Thank you for any assistance.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

To apply class according to first letter of css you can make function that will return the class according to surname like.

```
 //use css binding to bind this method
 self.getClass=function(data){
   var x= data.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    return x+"class";
 }
```

in view:-

```
//for block of letters
<div data-bind="foreach: filters" style='clear:both; float:left;'>
   <span class='letter'  data-bind="click: $parent.setActiveFilter, text: title,css: $parent.getClass(title)"></span>
</div>

 //for list of names
<td data-bind="text: lastName,css: $parent.getClass(lastName)"></td>
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/191/) for css class

For more information about [**css binding**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)

And for paging you can have a look at this [site](http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/07/11/paging-lists-with-knockout/)

Comment: Thanks for this..How can i get this query on the Letters rather than the main observable collection.  I want to make it really clear which "letters" have values beneath them rather than highlight the items.

Comment: do you want to highlight only letter not lastName?actually i didn't get clearly what do you want to achieve?

Comment: So the blocks of letters at the top..i want them to have a css class applied to each letter where the observable collection has a last name that starts with that letter.

Comment: Hi there..i don't think this is working.  The Letter filter need to look into the observable collection of people not filters.  if you see from this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/EZUEF/192/  That everything is set as selected where if you click on the letter "i" there are no results therefore that letter should not be "selected"